# how to change the variable at once for a set of file with the name in a list

Tags: r

I have filelist `filelist<- c("file1", "file2","file4", "file4")`, each one stands for a df in my enviroment,  and each file has variable `score`, I would like to change score value all at once.

what should i do so I can use the filelist to looping the codes to changed the value.

My codes are here, it won't work, but might give you an idea what i am trying to get:

```
for i to length(filelist){
  paste0(fillist[i],"$score") <- mapvalues(paste0(fillist[i],"$score"), 
          from=value$A, 
          to=value$B)
}
```

Thanks. My problem is how to get `fileX$score` instead of `"fileX$score"`

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have to read the files one by one (store them in a temp variable) and then change the value in the temp variable and save it again

Comment: if I read those df into a list, then use lapply or map to change the value, how can I put them back to the environment? I sort of have the direction, but not sure how to move forward. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
fileReader <- function(filename){
    if(grepl("csv$", filename)) return(read.csv(filename))
    # And so on...
}

fileReader <- function(data, filename){
    if(grepl("rds$", filename)) saveRDS(data, filename)
    # And so on...
}

changeFile <- function(df){
    df$score <- correct_value
    return(df)
}

for(file in filelist){
    temp <- fileReader(file)
    temp <- changeFile(temp)
    fileSaver(temp, file)
}
```